# orbeon: improving reusability of orbeon code

Tags: orbeon, xforms

If there are multiple date fields that have the same constraint or multiple text-area with the same constraint

Is it possible to reuse the constraint used by a bind, across similar constraints?

say text-area 1 has constraint

```
if(string-length(.) &gt; 500)
    then substring(.,1,500)
else .
```

and text-area 2 has constraint

```
if(string-length(.) &gt; 500)
    then substring(.,1,500)
else .
```

is it possible to have the constraint at a common location and at each bind call the particular constraint and reuse the code?

Comment: How will the textarea nodenames look like. Will they be something like <textarea-1/> and <textarea-2/> or completely irrelevant names like <abc/> and </xyz>?

Comment: @KaipaMSarma node-name can be anything. here the constraint is referencing the node by using the ".". So, if it is different node name, i was thinking some think like parameter passing (here full node-name passing) can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a single `bind` where the `nodeset` expression points to the two nodes corresponding to your two text areas. For instance:

```
<bind nodeset="/my-root/(text-area-1 | text-area-2)" constraint="…"/>
```

(In the future, a capability to define functions that are more like reusable XPath expressions might be added to XForms, allowing you to also easily reuse XPath expressions in other situations.)

Comment: But if text-area-2 is not in the /my-root, then the xpath expression becomes too complex. It will be great to see the resusable XPath expressions in futre.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am following you. If you have two `<xforms:bind>` with the same constraint, but a different XPath expressions for `nodeset`, say `<xforms:bind nodeset="xpath1" constraint="…"/>` and `<xforms:bind nodeset="xpath2" constraint="…"/>`, you can avoid duplicating the constraint by writing `<xforms:bind nodeset="xpath1 | xpath2" constraint="…"/>`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @avernet Yep, whatever you said is correct. I was just concerned about the xpath expression which becomes too complex if we add many nodeset with "|" operator and one should be very careful that they wont write an expression which picks unwanted node(say x) because if they already have an bind for that node 'x' then the resultant bind will be boolean of both and debugging becomes difficult.

Comment: @avernet i asked this question in view of performance improvement through reducing the code size, and i was able to achieve the size reduction (around 20kB in a xform file of size 940kb). But i am concerned about the complexity of node-set that i use in the bind. Say, i have a reference to 100+ nodes for a single bind. will it have any adverse effect on performance.

Comment: @NaveenBabu Unfortunately I think that the only way to know for sure about performance here is to measure both solutions.

Comment: @avernet is there some application to measure the performance at this minute level? as a 20kb size reduction performance change cant be noticed without actually going to milli-second level

Comment: @NaveenBabu You'd measure performance of a form created with Orbeon Forms just as you would test the performance of another web app. Tools like Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools will tell you the exact time it took to load a page. If you want to get an average over many loads, you can use JMeter, or the more enterprise-level HP LoadRunner.